# How to change value of javascript variable with change in value of dropdown?

Tags: javascript

I have created a variable called "text" in javascript that takes value from drop-down menu.

```
var text = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
```

But when I load the script, `var text` only takes default value of drop-down. Even if I change value of drop-down, value of variable remains the same. I want that value of variable changes as value of drop-down changes. I updated javascript after reading answers

```
var text= "hi i am a coder";
var dropdown = document.getElementbyId("dropdown");
dropdown.addEventListener("change", function(){
text = dropdown.value;
});

var storyTextarea = document.getElementById("storytext");
storyTextarea.value = text;
```

After reading answers I tried above code but it didn't worked. I want `var text` to change it's value with change in dropdown and then a text-box with id="storytext" updates it's value based on value of variable. Please help. I am new at javascript, please explain. I will be very thankful to you. HTML -

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="text 0">...Select Paragraph...</option>
    <option value="text 1">text1</option>
    <option value="text 2">text2</option>
    <option value="text 3">text3</option>
    <option value="text 4">text4</option>
</select>

<div class="typebox">
            <textarea id="storytext" name="storytext" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
```

Comment: You will need to attach an `onchange` event to the dropdown and then save the current value in the text variable

Comment: Can you please share the HTML for the dropdown?

Comment: onchange is not necessarily needed. Please take a look at this sample from w3school - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_value2. You should be able to read the value anyhow.

Comment: In the example you just shared, the javascript function `myFunction` only runs when the button is clicked. So, if the user has changed the select option and then click the button, it will take the current value of the dropdown (select option)

Comment: @FemiOladeji, the button click is separate from the dropdown. Any time after the selection is changed if you read, you should get an updated value.

Comment: @user8235202 The HTML please.

Comment: @user8235202 I've edited my answer, the mistake you made was to put this statement `storyTextarea.value = text;` outside the change function. You know I said the onchange event runs every time the user changes an option so the changing of the value of `storyTextarea` should also happen in that function

Answer (score 0):

```
var text;
var dropdown = document.getElementbyId("dropdown");
dropdown.addEventListener("change", function(){
text = dropdown.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a change listener to your dropdown element. Try this example:

```
<h1>Current <span id="current"></span></h1>

<select id="animals">
  <option value="dog">Doge</option>
  <option value="cat">Ket</option>
</select>
```

JS Script:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('animals');
var currElem = document.getElementById('current');

currElem.innerHTML = elem.value;

animals.onchange = function(e) {
   currElem.innerHTML = e.target.value;
}
```

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare variable text at the beginning, and you'll assign value to it, value won't change when you change element in dropdown. You must attach an onchange action, and assign value inside onchange function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the html for the dropdown was setup this way

```
<select id="dropdown">
   <option value="text 0">...Select Paragraph...</option>
   <option value="text 1">text1</option>
   <option value="text 2">text2</option>
   <option value="text 3">text3</option>
   <option value="text 4">text4</option>
</select>
<div class="typebox">
   <textarea id="storytext" name="storytext" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

Then what you need to do is ensure that there's a javascript that runs whenever the user changes the gender option and the onchange event is what makes that happen

```
var text= "hi i am a coder";
var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
var storyTextarea = document.getElementById("storytext");
storyTextarea.value = text;
dropdown.addEventListener("change", function(){
text = dropdown.value;
  storyTextarea.value = text;
});
```

the `gender.addEventListener` is what is used to attach the change event to the dropdown. You can check it out on codepen https://codepen.io/femidotexe/pen/OgvXPo